# Spring + GWT, how to disable User Authorization request for a Insert Query?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

I'm currently working on supporting a Spring + GWT intranet application that was given to me on the last hour, I need to implement a dozen fixes to this software, including tests and stuff.

One thing that I could not find is that:

I have a view and a presenter, the presenter is responsible for the function that will initiate a query into the DB to insert an entity.

When I click the button, a User Authorization Request (login) pops up, requiring an additional login to conclude the operation.

I could not figure it out, where do I remove this kind of additional authorization request?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

It was a Annotation on top of a method on my `EntityRemoteServiceAsyncImpl`.

So if you have any problems with this check your class for `@RequireAuthorization`

Just remove or comment it out.